# Filter a dictionary based on values stored in an array

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary of the following format:

```
data={'city':np.array(['chicago','champaign','kansas city','dallas','champaign','chicago']),
  'state':np.array(['IL','IL','KA','TX','IL','IL']), 'transaction_dt':np.array(['1-1-2018','2-1-2018','3-1-2018','7-1-2018','1-1-2018','2-1-2018'])}
```

I want to get the transaction_dt for all transactions that happened in the state IL. How can I do this in a dictionary? (I know how to do it in a pd dataframe but dictionaries are so different!!)

Comment: is there any particular reason you are using `numpy.ndarray` objects here?

Comment: I've used this dataset in my question just as an example, but the actual data I'm working on uses numpy.ndarray so yes, the reason is that's the format in which I was given the data

Comment: Why not just put it in a data-frame?

Comment: Can't! I would if I could! #ilovePandas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a boolean mask:

```
import numpy as np

data = {'city': np.array(['chicago','champaign','kansas city','dallas','champaign','chicago']),
        'state': np.array(['IL','IL','KA','TX','IL','IL']),
        'transaction_dt': np.array(['1-1-2018','2-1-2018','3-1-2018','7-1-2018','1-1-2018','2-1-2018'])}

res = data['transaction_dt'][data["state"] == "IL"]
```

Output:

```
>>> res
array(['1-1-2018', '2-1-2018', '1-1-2018', '2-1-2018'],
      dtype='<U8')
```

Answer (score 0):

I omitted that this is `np.array` but they will work same

```
In [1]: data = {
   ...:     'city':['chicago','champaign','kansas city','dallas','champaign','chicago'],
   ...:     'state':['IL','IL','KA','TX','IL','IL'],
   ...:     'transaction_dt':['1-1-2018','2-1-2018','3-1-2018','7-1-2018','1-1-2018','2-1-2018']
   ...: }

In [2]: desired_transactions = [transaction_dl
   ...:                         for state, transaction_dl in zip(data['state'], data['transaction_dt'])
   ...:                         if state == 'IL']
   ...:

In [3]: desired_transactions
Out[3]: ['1-1-2018', '2-1-2018', '1-1-2018', '2-1-2018']
```